# How to use draggable from jquery-ui in the jquery-ui node module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, npm

I'm trying to enable drag-drop of images in my page and want to use jquery-ui. Like the rest of my project's dependencies I want to install jquery-ui from the npm [jquery-ui package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui).

I only want to use the draggable and droppable widgets however when I include the scripts (after jQuery is included) I get two errors

> TypeError: $.ui is undefined

and

> TypeError: $.widget is undefined

Obviously I'm missing other dependencies from jquery-ui, but what?